# Python PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/pytest/ - cannot install packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pytest

I have an issue with installing packages on my WIN11. Until today, I used Python 2.7, which worked, but I upgraded to 3 because I want to use pytest. Now, however, I cannot install packages.

My Python version 3.11.0 and pip version is 22.3. Here is the screenshot of what I see:

[image: Screenshot of Console showing Python version and pip install pytest results]

What I've tried:

- I reinstalled and rebooted
- I modified the environmental variables
- I ran the cmd prompt as admin
- I disabled path length limit too.
- I tried pip3 instead of pip.
- I tried installing Python to another directory
- I tried installing packages in Pycharm
- I downloaded the packages manually from pypi and tried installing them

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you try something like `pip install pytest --user`?. Also, the error states that there was a permission error while trying to contact the server. Check if your connection works properly from the command line and I would also move to another folder (out of System32, maybe Desktop)

Comment: pip install pytest --user did not work too. Now I installed Python on Desktop but still the same issue... :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIP install and Python requests get PermissionError on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71999820/pip-install-and-python-requests-get-permissionerror-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/71999820/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71999820/pip-install-and-python-requests-get-permissionerror-on-windows) this is a bug in python. 3.10.4, 30.10, 30.9, 30.8 is not working for me. Only python 3.7.4. I just downgraded to python 3.7.4 and now installing packages works well!